# Class $C$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, real-numbers

> How do you prove the following:
>
> In general, a $C^k$ function is contained in $C^{k-1}$ for any $k$.

Why is this true? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you know the definition of $C^k$, and can you write it here? Once it's written out properly it should be virtually trivial to see why this is true....

Comment: ...if a function has k continuous derivatives, it has k-1 continuous derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f\in C^k$ means that $f$ is $k$ times differentiable and the $k$th derivative is continuous.  In particular $f$ is $k-1$ times differentiable and the $(k-1)$th derivative is continuous (since $f^{(k)}$ exists)